# Opening a form with the tile added to the workspace

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I created a workspace in DefaultDashboard. I added a custom-developed form as a tile to this workspace. When I reach the form with the tile I added, the form opens in a new record type. But when I refresh the page with F5, the form opens as I want.

[image: workspace screenshot]

Added custom form in workspace tile:

[image: added custom form in workspace tile]

Opened form from workspace tile:

[image: opened form from workspace tile]

After F5:

[image: refreshed same form]

**I have this problem not only in this form but in most custom forms in general. This form is the example.**

If we take the standard InventOnhandItem form as an example, when we open it as a box, it opens the form as a new record. In other words, it opens in the same way in standard forms.The difference with my form is that it works in standard form without having to refresh the page with F5.

How can I solve this situation? What I want is the version opened with F5.